# Spring 4 java configuration, separated wars for front/backend, setting home page for localhost:port/myAppsName/

Tags: java, html, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am currently working on a project which is separated into frontend (html5, jquery, css) and backend (Spring4 mvc with java config -no web.xml-, exposing rest for the view to consume it), each of which has its own pom that depends on the same parent pom.

[Project's tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W8Ye.jpg)

When I compile the main project, 2 wars are generated (front and backend), which I later deploy in tomcat 7.

Backend is working fine (i've already tested it with psotman) and frontend works fine also if I open the html from outside tomcat (when I open index.html from a folder on my computer). However when I deploy the frontend war together with te backend war in tomcat and enter "localhost:8080/myAppsName/", http eror 404 is thrown. I understand that the html can't be found in order to render the index page.

[frontend tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I86iJ.jpg)

Backend AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.fedelaper.spring")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/frontend/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

}
```

Backend AppInitializer.java:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

I DO have a web.xml in project frontend which is actually empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

</web-app>
```

My question is: 
- How should I set index.html to be the default home page of my app when entering localhost:8080/myAppsName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your frontend modules web.xml file with welcome-file-list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
I had also to move index.html from "/frontend/index.html" to "/index.html"